# css cjuidialog on yii

Tags: css, yii, cjuidialog

I'm trying to give a style to my cjuidialog on yii. 
I've got this into the cjuidialog:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/survey/style.php">
```

The problem is that this style affects to the entire page. How can I give a style only to the dialog?

```
 <?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
        'id'=>'previewdialog',
        // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
        'options'=>array(
            'title'=>'Template Preview',
            'autoOpen'=>false,
            'draggable'=>true,
            'modal'=>false,
            'width'=>900,
        )
    ));

    echo 'Preview';

    $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: can you post the code of `cjuidialog` ? And why do you have `/style.php` as `stylesheet` ?

Comment: I use style.php because I need variables into my css.